# Can't understand this block of code in the course "Convolutional Neural Networks in TensorFlow" Week 1

Tags: python, tensorflow, matplotlib, conv-neural-network

The block of code is:

```
for i, img_path in enumerate(next_cat_pix+next_dog_pix):  <-----
    sp = plt.subplot(nrows, ncols, i + 1)  <-----
    sp.axis('Off')
    img = mpimg.imread(img_path)  <-----
    plt.imshow(img)
```

Where imported libraries were:

```
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

And *next_cat_pix, next_dog_pix* are 2 lists containing the training cats and dogs images directories.

This block of code is taken from the course "Convolutional Neural Networks in TensorFlow" Week 1 in the specialization "TensorFlow in Practice" in Coursera.

It's printing the images properly, I just can't understand those marked lines.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please repeat [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the intro tour.    What do  you not understand about those lines?  Make reference to the method documentation and to the items you include in the code context.

Comment: Also include your output from running the code on a sample data set; refer to specifics in the output values and images.